# Android: Styling inline html link in TextView

Tags: android

I have a TextView with some html text containing a link.
I added a style to the TextView and now the link is not visible as a link.

The string:

```
<string name="strPrivacyPolicyAndContact">See our %1$s Privacy Policy %2$s or contact us for more information: support@beatrixkiddo.com.</string>
```

The `TextView` xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/privacyAndContact"
    style="@style/NewFont_Label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/strPrivacyPolicyAndContact" />
```

The `NewFont_Label` style:

```
<style name="NewFont_Label">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="variant">medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/label</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.02</item>
</style>
```

The code:

```
private static final String PRIVACY_HREF = "<a href=\"http://www.beatrixkiddo.com\privacy\">";
private static final String END_TAG = "</a>";

privacyAndContact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.privacyAndContact);
privacyAndContact.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.strPrivacyPolicyAndContact, PRIVACY_HREF, END_TAG)));
```

Before adding the style:

[image]

After adding the style:

[image]

The question:

I've tried adding all possible html tags with no result.
How do I style the link with an underline or a color?

**Update**

I've tried SpannableString, but it's impact is being annulled by the applying of the `style` on the TextView:

```
SpannableString privacy = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.strPrivacyPolicyAndContact));
privacy.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.beatrixkiddo.com/privacy"), 13, 26, 0);
privacy.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 13, 26, 0);
privacy.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 13, 26, 0);
privacyAndContact.setText(privacy);
```

So the spannable doesn't work in this case either.

Comment: Use spannableString instead.

Comment: Add parent text style

Comment: FYI `Html.fromHtml(string)` deprecated in `Nougat`. use other method of `Html.fromHtml(string,int)` and use fallback method for below devices

Comment: The SpannableString doesn't work for me in this case due to the `style` on the TextView. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

change this two lines only.

```
private static final String PRIVACY_HREF = "<u><b><font color='green' ><a href='http://www.beatrixkiddo.com/privacy' >Privacy Policy";
private static final String END_TAG = "</a></font></b></u>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(PRIVACY_HREF+END_TAG));
```

Comment: TextView doesn't support deprecated html tags. Tried it.

Comment: @Ambran, textview supports basic html element but you don't know how to code html+java.please try my above code.

Comment: The attached `style` kills off every other applied styling. Tried with SpannableString with no result either.

Comment: Did you test with the kind of `Style` block I've attached to the TextView? Can you post the code? I would really like to try it.

Comment: leave style.just put above three lines in any textview and run it.it has to display green link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144656/discussion-between-vasant-and-ambran).